# Protractor form validation caused Failed expectation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Im very new to protractor and im finding hard to test form validation

```
<input name="emailid" data-ng-model="contactInfo.email" class="input-padding-five" type="email"
  required data-ng-class="{'error-border' : reg.$submitted && reg.emailid.$invalid }" />

<span class="span-error" data-ng-if="reg.$submitted && reg.emailid.$invalid" data-ng-bind-template="Enter valid Email id"></span>
```

I tried doing follwing

```
expect(element(by.css('input[name="emailid"]')),'ng-invalid').toBe(true);
expect(element(by.css('input[name="emailid"]'))).toMatch(/error-border/);
```

still didnot help.............Any help is much appreciated.......Thank you in advance

Comment: What are you trying to test exactly? Are you checking if the elements are displayed on the webpage? Thanks

Comment: yes...checking for the Enter valid Email id is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the dependent function on the elements to perform operations on them. In your case, use `isDisplayed()` function to check if the error span is displayed. Here's how -

```
var err = element(by.css('.span-error'));
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(err), 5000); //If the error span takes time to be visible, use wait() function
expect(err.isDisplayed()).toBe(true); //Checks if span error is displayed
```

You can use similar functions to check other properties of elements. For ex, use `getText()` to get text value of an element.

Hope it helps.